# rust native_tls unable to tell to the server to trust only one specific client

Tags: ssl, rust

my use case is, I need to encrypt a connection between a client and a server in a closed network. I think TLS is a good idea for this.

My server must trust only one specific client, my client must trust ony one specific server. So I decided to generate two self-signed certificate using openssl cli. Here my working dir:

```sh
tls
├── ca.crt
├── ca.der
├── ca.key
├── ca.srl
├── certs
├── crl
├── index.txt
├── newcerts
│   ├── client.crt
│   ├── client.csr
│   ├── client.der
│   ├── client.key
│   ├── server.crt
│   ├── server.csr
│   ├── server.der
│   ├── server.key
├── newidents
│   ├── client.pfx
│   ├── server.pfx
```

I also generate my own CA and create identity file pkcs12.

I want to setup a server who trust only my client. `native_tls::TlsConnectorBuilder` provide the `add_root_certificate` but `native_tls::TlsAcceptorBuilder` don't.

So how can I do this ? On server side I have something like:

```rust
    let server_identity = identity_from_pkcs12(&identity_filepath, &identity_password)
        .expect("Unable to create instance of identity");

    let listener = tcp_listener("127.0.0.1", 4443).expect("Cannot listen on port");

   // how can I specify a client certificate here ? 
    let acceptor = native_tls::TlsAcceptor::builder(server_identity)
        .build()
        .expect("Unable to create a TLS Acceptor using identity file");
```

Comment: Is your client running on untrusted machines?

Comment: The client running on a trusted machine. But I don't want to have another computer allowed to create a TLS session with my server.